# How to display a single dimensional array in FlatList

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

You would think that this would be the easiest thing in the world to find an example of but everthing I found online has always had a JSON file as the data source so there are keys to reference

stuff like this...eg item.name etc

```
const list = [
  {
    name: 'Amy Farha',
    subtitle: 'Vice President'
  },
  {
    name: 'Chris Jackson',
    avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
    subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
  },
  ... // more items
]

keyExtractor = (item, index) => index.toString()

renderItem = ({ item }) => (
  <ListItem
    title={item.name}
    subtitle={item.subtitle}
    leftAvatar={{
      source: item.avatar_url && { uri: item.avatar_url },
      title: item.name[0]
    }}
  />
)
```

My data source is just a plain single dimension array, no keys or identifiers of any kind. The data is what it is and wont be changed

```
data = ['value1','value2','value3',...]
```

The code I have so far (which obviously doesnt work) is

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { FlatList, ListItem } from 'react-native'

<FlatList
      data={this.state.data}
      renderItem={({ item }) => ( 
        <ListItem
        key={item.id}
        />
      )}
    />
```

Im guessing I need to use the `keyExtractor` somewhere to generate an `id` but how do I reference the actual values in the data to display them if it doesnt have an identifier in the `data` like a json would?

Comment: You could simply `renderItem={({ item, index }) => <ListItem key={index} title={item} />}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<FlatList
    data={this.state.data}
    keyExtractor={item => item}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
      <ListItem
        title={item}
      />
    )}
  />

const ListItem = ({ title }) => (
  <View>
    <Text>{title}</Text>
     ...
  </View>
);
```

Comment: I got an error=> Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Comment: I you have ListItem component in your project ... there's something wrong in it... could you please add you ListItem component to your question?

Comment: I have imported list item like this...    import { FlatList, ListItem } from 'react-native'

Comment: I guessed that from your question :) ... there's no build-in ListItem component in react-native ...we need to implement it :)

Comment: Can I use this instead? https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/listitem.html